# Beginner, basic trig table in increments of 5 degrees

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

For a class that I am taking I am trying to create a program that produces a table of sin(), cos(), and tan() values for angles from 0 to 180 degrees in steps of 5 degrees.

!http://i65.tinypic.com/14ahliq.jpg

So far I have the following code, which produces an introduction and the first two lines of the table, but I cannot figure out how to get it to repeat.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Angles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program computes the");
        System.out.println("sin(), cos(), and tan() values");
        System.out.println("for angles from 0 to 180 degrees");
        System.out.println("in steps of 5 degrees.");

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Angle\tSin()\tCos()\tTan()");
        double Anglex = 0;
        for(double i = 5;i <= Anglex;i += 5) {
            Anglex = 0 + i;
        }
        double Sinx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Anglex));
        double Cosx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Anglex));
        double Tanx = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Anglex));

        System.out.println(Anglex + "\t" + Sinx + "\t" + Cosx + "\t" + Tanx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recast your `for` loop to

`for (double Anglex = 0; Anglex <= 180; Anglex += 5){`

Note well the opening brace to enclose multiple subsequent statements. Don't forget to balance it with a closing `}`; probably after the `println` call.

Using a `double` as a loop index is not to everyone's taste (you can get yourself into trouble if you are not using whole numbers), but this is fine in this instance, particularly also as you are using `<=` as the stopping condition.

Starting variable names with an upper case letter is also to be discouraged in Java as it's unconventional.

Comment: Thank you, recasting my for loop and adding the {} helped and now my code works, and thank you for the tips on using a double as a loop index and upper case letters for variable names! I am completely new to programming so you were a great help :)

Answer (score 3):

Is not really ok that you ask people on forums to solve your assignments. 
Otherwise, several issues with your little program (didn't test, please do it yourself).

1. `anglex` should start at `0` and stop at `180`. So `for(int anglex=0; anglex<=180; anglex+=5)`. Use `anglex` instead of `i`, inside the loop.
2. the calculations for `sinx`, `cosx`, `tanx` and the printing of the new line should be inside the curlies `{}`. As your code is right now, the only thing inside the loop is the increment of `anglex`.

Sorry for not providing the full solution, pretty sure you can do it.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I did not ask anyone to solve my assignment for me simply to advise me on what I am doing wrong. I am going to school to teach K-8 math so I am not sure why this class is a requirement and I have no prior experience in java programming. I wrote the entire code that I have so far by myself, which may seem easy to people who know what they are doing but I myself do not.

Comment: ok, got it. The thing is that the "advise" for fixing the code would solve completely your assignment. Sorry to hear you need this class for your k-8 math teaching job, I agree it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(double i = 5;i <= Anglex;i += 5) {
    Anglex = 0 + i;
    double Sinx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Anglex));
    double Cosx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Anglex));
    double Tanx = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Anglex));
}
```

Enclose the above statements inside a { and }. The for loop applies for only the first statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop only applies on the Anglex = 0+i line.

Add {} to the whole section that should be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("This program computes the");
    System.out.println("sin(), cos(), and tan() values");
    System.out.println("for angles from 0 to 180 degrees");
    System.out.println("in steps of 5 degrees.");

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Angle\tSin()\tCos()\tTan()");
    double maxAngleX = 180.0;
    for (double angleX = 5; angleX <= maxAngleX; angleX += 5) {

      double Sinx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleX));
      double Cosx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleX));
      double Tanx = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(angleX));

      System.out.println(angleX + "\t" + Sinx + "\t" + Cosx + "\t" + Tanx);

    }
}
```